# httphandler generated png not displaying in older browser (IE8)

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer-8

I have made an httphandler that shrinks an image and returns it as PNG. This works fine on my Vista PC with IE 9, but not on some old XP machines with IE 8. It seems strange that this should be a browser issue, but to me it looks like that. But, I am thinking that since I produce the PNG on the server, I must do something wrong in the code.

The httphandler (simplified):

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="ShowPicture" %>
using System.Data;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;

public class ShowPicture : IHttpHandler {

public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
    // byteArray comes from database
    // maxWidth and maxHeight comes from Request
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(
        Common.ResizeImageFromArray(byteArray, maxWidth, maxHeight));
}
```

And the function called (simplified as well):

```
public static byte[] ResizeImageFromArray(byte[] array, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
{
    byte[] picArray = array;

    if (maxWidth > 0 || maxHeight > 0)  // Resize the image
    {
        Bitmap dbbmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(new MemoryStream(array));

        if (dbbmp.Width > maxWidth || dbbmp.Height > maxHeight)
        {
            // Calculate the max width/height factor

            Bitmap resized = new Bitmap(dbbmp, newWidth, newHeight);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            resized.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

            picArray = new Byte[ms.Length - 1];
            ms.Position = 0;
            ms.Read(picArray, 0, picArray.Length);
            ms.Close();
        }
    }
    return picArray;
}
```

I appreciate any ideas and/or input. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Older ie versions have a lot of problems with png, maybe you can try to save it as jpg.

Comment: Do you know what kind of problems? I am considering to just change this to JPG, as this would solve my problem, but curious as I am I'd like to find this out (and learn more).

Comment: http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/ie-transparency-problems/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I realize that there are problems With the opacity, but still the PNG is not displayed incorrectly, it is not displayed at all. Only the red X icon appears, but the Dimensions of the Picture is correct. I read somewhere that I might need to set the pixelformat in the Bitmap constructor, but I couldn't figure out the right setting.

Comment: Easy: `Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Width, Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)` if you want alpha channel, `PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb` if you don't want aplha

Comment: Also, I see you are not setting explicitly the ContentLength of your response, try setting it (it's supposed to be mandatory if the connection is not closed and transfer encoding is not set).

Comment: I have seen the constructor With the diffrent pixelformats, but I didn't understand how to put the original bitmap (dbbmp) into the resized bitmap (resized).

Comment: I'm going to post it as response, but don't take it as a real response, is to have code clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resize with different format:

```
Bitmap resizedBitmap = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(resizedBitmap);
g.DrawImage(originalBitmap, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, resizedBitmap.Size), new Rectangle(Point.Empty, originalBitmap.Size), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
g.Dispose();
```

With that you will have yopur scaled bitmap, also you can play with the Graphics object options to get better quality/faster processing times.

Also, to convert your MemoryStream to array is better to use ms.ToArray();

```
picArray = ms.ToArray();
```

This way you don't need to create the array by yourself.